# How do I create a date range query when the date is stored in separate rows?

Tags: mysql

A table called "report":

```
|id|report_field_id|report_value_row_id|report_value|
|1|1|1|2012-01-05|
|2|2|1|Some text|
|3|3|1|109.00|
|4|1|2|2012-01-06|
|5|2|2|More text|
|6|3|3|889.73|
|7|1|3|2012-01-07|
|8|2|3|More text|
|9|3|3|889.73|
```

I would like create a select query that sums report_value where report__field_id is equal to 3 and where report_field_id 1 is a certain date or between a certain date range. I'm not sure if I should use a sub query, join or what. I'm still quite new to MySQL, but I really need this to work for a project I'm working on.

Comment: With all due respect, this table design is entirely non-sensible. Why was it designed like this in the first place?

Comment: Because our app is not sure how many fields and what data types to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's try this:

```
select
    sum(r.report_value) as value
from
    report r
where
    r.report_field_id = 3
    and exists
    (
        select
            1
        from
            report r1
        where
            r1.report_value_row_id = r.report_value_row_id
            and str_to_date(report_value, '%Y-%m-%d') between '2012-01-04' and '2012-01-05'
            and r1.report_field_id = 1
    )
```

This query being said, your table design is rather abysmal. Why don't you just have columns for Date, Name, and Value? That way, you could just do `select sum(value) from report where date between '2012-01-04' and '2012-01-05'` and make your life easy! I would sincerely question your database design practices. This is a relational database, not a key-value store--use it like one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this feels like the sort of thing I need. However your code gives me a null return. I'm guessing you also made a typo; shouldn't "reports r1" be "report r1", assuming my table is called report?

Comment: The table was designed in this way because our app is never sure how many fields we will be using in a given report. They change in number and in data type.

Comment: Found another typo, and once fixed it works as expected. "%Y-%M-%d" should be "%Y-%m-%d'. Thanks for your help! Is your answer an example of a sub query?

Comment: @trnsfrmr - Glad you got it working! I've edited the typos for you. At any rate, yes, this is a type of subquery. However, it's not a correlated subquery (run for each row). Rather, this runs the subquery and then uses a join (due to the `exists` command) to match that result data to your previously returned set.

Comment: Interesting! The more I learn about MySQL the more I like it.

Comment: @trnsfrmr - This syntax and its usage is pretty consistent across all the major RDBMS's. Databases are pretty fantastic things :)